# Duplicate results in Google

Tags: support, seo

It's good for Stack Overflow to be listed in Google as much as possible, but I think it's inconvenient for users when the same topic appears several times, like:

[image]
* (Search phrase used: `"is not defined on the instance but referenced during render." vue`)*

Maybe it's good if you create "canonical" or something, to avoid such duplicates in Google Search results.

Comment: MSE dup: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/297651/duplicate-results-in-google-search-is-it-a-bug.  If you noticed, the 2nd link is to an answer on the question